# Installin Apache Pulsar C++ Client on a Mac

Tags: boost, cmake, homebrew, boost-python, apache-pulsar

I am trying to follow the following instructions to install Apache Pulsar C++ client on a Mac:
https://github.com/apache/pulsar/tree/master/pulsar-client-cpp#compile-on-mac-os-x

Unfortunately, I am getting the following response when I run `cmake .` step:

```
12:25 AM rp:~/fp/pulsar/pulsar-client-cpp$(master)>cmake .
-- BUILD_TESTS:  ON
-- BUILD_PYTHON_WRAPPER:  ON
-- LINK_STATIC:  OFF
-- USE_LOG4CXX:  OFF
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:  RelWithDebInfo
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/include (found version "1.71.0") found components:  program_options regex system
-- PYTHON: 2.7.16
CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2003 (message):
  No header defined for python-mt; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:149 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2003 (message):
  No header defined for python-py27; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:149 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2003 (message):
  No header defined for python27-mt; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:149 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.15.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2003 (message):
  No header defined for python27-mt; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:160 (find_package)


-- Found Boost: /usr/local/include (found version "1.71.0") found components:  python27-mt
-- HAS_ZSTD: 1
-- HAS_SNAPPY: 0
-- Using Boost Python libs: /usr/local/opt/python@2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_python27-mt.dylib;Boost_PYTHON37-MT_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at python/CMakeLists.txt:70 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find Boost Python library


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/rp/fp/pulsar/pulsar-client-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have used brew to install boost, boost-python and cmake, but it appears that cmake doesn't see the python boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a work around by editing the main `CMakeLists.txt` file under `pulsar/pulsar-client-cpp` :

```
if (PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING MATCHES "^3.+$")
        MESSAGE(STATUS "DETECTED Python 3")
        string(REPLACE "." ";" PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_NO_LIST ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING})
        list(GET PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_NO_LIST 0 PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_MAJOR)
        list(GET PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_NO_LIST 1 PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_MINOR)
        set(BOOST_PYTHON_NAME_POSTFIX ${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_MAJOR}${PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_MINOR})
        # For python3 the lib name is boost_python3
        set(BOOST_PYTHON_NAME_LIST python3;python3-mt;python-py${BOOST_PYTHON_NAME_POSTFIX};python${BOOST_PYTHON_NAME_POSTFIX}-mt;python${BOOST_PYTHON_NAME_POSTFIX})
    else ()
        # Regular boost_python
        set(BOOST_PYTHON_NAME_LIST python3;python37;python;python-mt;python-py27;python27-mt;python27)
    endif ()
```

This solution does require to use `brew install boost-python3`.

I suspect that if `python` is switched around with `python27` it would work as well. My `python` installation is 2.7.